# Why do the x, y coordinates for HTML5 SVG start in the top left?

Tags: html, svg, coordinates

Almost everyone who's had a single math class would expect the coordinates to have their origin at the bottom left corner.

Why do they start in the top left? Is this indicated anywhere in the documentation?